# Build error while trying to install airpal

Tags: presto

I'm trying to get [airpal](https://github.com/airbnb/airpal) going and have gotten to:

```
git clone https://github.com/airbnb/airpal.git
sudo apt-get install npm nodejs-legacy
./gradlew clean shadowJar
```

and get the following message:

```
:installAssets

> contextify@0.1.13 install /home/carl/presto/airpal/src/main/resources/assets/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

Usage: gyp_main.py [options ...] [build_file ...]

gyp_main.py: error: no such option: --no-parallel
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/carl/.gradle/nodejs/node-v0.10.33-linux-
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/carl/.gradle/nodejs/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/carl/presto/airpal/src/main/resources/assets/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! contextify@0.1.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.13 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.

:installAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

BUILD FAILED
```

What am I missing? I have a few suspicions with the --no-parallel error, and attempted to run node-gyp rebuild got got a binding.gyp file not found error. End of Question. The following text aims to satisfy SO's code-to-detail ratio.

I'm not too familiar with node or node-gyp, so I'm hoping someone can help me out. I've removed the majority of the stacktrace to get within the ratio, but I'm also worried about losing context by removing too much.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a few people are having that issue or something similar. Check out these points which may help you solve your issue. https://github.com/airbnb/airpal/issues/113

I altered `"browser-sync": "~2.6.5"` in `src/main/resources/assets/package.json` which did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I didn't have "browser-sync" in the `src/main/resources/assets/package.json` file, but I added it within the "devDependencies": {...} section (and gave it the "~2.6.5" value). So it looks something like this:

`...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^4.0.0",
    "babelify": "^5.0.3",
    "browserify": "~13.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "~2.6.5",
    "browserify-shim": "~3.8.12",
    ...`

Second, after you run `sudo apt-get install npm nodejs-legacy` then you want to run the `sudo ./gradlew clean shadowJar -Dairpal.useLocalNode` command, not the one you specified (which downloads its own node and npm packages).

Also be sure you have gradle installed correctly first, it's in the PATH, etc.